# How to use an algorithm to make the white list function more effective?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have designed a white list function to filter file pathes in windows.
There are three types of patterns to filter:

- filter pathes according to suffix, such as all txt files.
- filter pathes from left, for example, filter all pathes which start with "C:\Windows\System32"
- filter pathes which contain a special words, for example, filter all pathes which contain "system".

The patterns are saved in the format:

```
patternList = [{'type': 'suffix', 'content':'\.txt'},
            {'type': 'keyword', 'content':'system'},
            {'type': 'left', 'content': 'C:\Windows\System32'}]
```

every dict is a pattern, and all patterns are in a list called patternList.

Then, I have another list called pathInfoObjectList which contain many objects, each objects has an attribute called "filelist", which is a list. In the filelist, there are some file pathes.

Now, I want to use the pattern to delete every path in filelist.

My method is to change the pattern to regex to finish the work.

My codes is here:

```
patternRegexList = []
for each in patternList:
    if each['type'] == 'suffix':
        patternRegex = '.*?' + each['content'] + '$'
    elif each['type'] == 'keyword':
        patternRegex = '.*?' + each['content'] + '.*?'
    elif each['type'] == 'left':
        patternRegex = '^' + each['content'] + '.*?'
    patternRegexList.append(patternRegex)


for pathInfoObject in pathInfoObjectList:
    for path in pathInfoObject.filelist[:]:
        for patternRegex in patternRegexList:
            if re.match(patternRegex, path):
                pathInfoObject.filelist.remove(path)
                break
```

But I think my algorithm is so stupid, and it is [image: O(n^{3})].

Do you have a smart way to finish the task?

As now I have found the lacking of the knowledge of algorithm makes my codes ineffective, do you have some suggestions for me to learn algorithm better? I think learning by reading *Introduction to algorithms* is too slow. Is there  more effective way to learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like it's more like a blacklist than a whitelist, but if I get it wrong, it's easy to fix it.

I tried to express your rules in a clearer and more flexible manner first. I tried to avoid using useless regex too, they probably cost you a lot of time. Finally by using `any` I avoid testing each exclusion rule when the first has matched. Using a `continue` in your for loop has the same effect.

```
exclusion_rules = [
    lambda path: path.endswith('.txt'),
    lambda path: 'system' in path,
    lambda path: path.startswith(r'c:\Windows\System32')]

for pathInfoObject in pathInfoObjectList:
    pathInfoObject.filelist = filter(
        lambda path: not any(rule(path) for rule in exclusion_rules),
        pathInfoObject.filelist)
```

Another way to do so with list comprehehension instead of filter:

```
for pathInfoObject in pathInfoObjectList:
    pathInfoObject.filelist = [path for path in pathInfoObject.filelist if
                               not any(rule(path) for rule in exclusion_rules)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. the code lines are really decrease, but how about the Big O?  Maybe your code is ![](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?O%28n%5E%7B2%7D%29)? Or still ![](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?O%28n%5E%7B2%7D%29)


Here I writed my code in Python, so do you, nonetheless, my boss force me to use Java6 to implement the function, you know, **lambda** appears in Java8.... and Java has not filter either....

Comment: The gain is focused on the use of "any" to avoid checking an already discarded file and by avoiding use of regex. Also as `exclusion_rules` are checked in order, you may put the most discriminant rules first, to avoid computing others most of the time. You can easily rewrite those two points in Java, BTW thanks for asking in Python !

Comment: I love Python but hate Java.  Thanks your answer again.

Comment: Once implemented, tell us if the performance gain is enough, and how many files per second were treated before / after.

Comment: In fact even by using the stupid way, everything is OK, because there are only 4 patterns, and the `len(pathInfoObjectList) <= 10`, and `len(pathInfoObject.filelist) <= 100`. I asked this question was just because I thought my code was stupid and ugly.

Comment: OK so the only really ugly part of your code was to not stop checking your rules once a file is actually removed. And the less-ugly part was using costy regex when you don't need them :)

Comment: `O(1)` I can't, you're having `n` files × `m` rules, and at a point you'll have to match some of the rules against some of the files...

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need *re* for that - just use simple string matching. You also does not need dictionary here.

```
patternList = (( 'suffix', '.txt'),
               ('keyword', 'system'),
               ('left',  'C:\Windows\System32'))

matchFuncList = []
for pattern, text in patternList:
    if pattern == 'suffix':
        matchFuncList.append(lambda s: s.endswith(text))
    elif pattern == 'keyword':
        matchFuncList.append(lambda s: text in s)
    elif pattern == 'left':
        matchFuncList.append(lambda s: s.startswith(text))
```

Now, don't remove values from lists - rebuild lists

```
for pathInfoObject in pathInfoObjectList:
    pathInfoObject.fileList = [path for path in pathInfoObject.fileList 
                               if not any(matchFunc(path) 
                                          for matchFunc in matchFuncList)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The key point is not how to define the patternList or if I need to use dict or tuple.  And because I have used `pathInfoObject.filelist[:]` to copy the list, there will not raise Exception, so why do you still suggest me do not remove items from list?

Comment: Removing from list is expensive operation; so - comparatively - is copying list. I just build a new list and replace old list reference with a new one. There's O(n\*m) worst case scenario, where _n_ is length of file list and _m_ - length of function list. Since _any_ shortcuts - exits on first failure - it should be closer to 0(n\*m/2)

Comment: @Mitangrice Also - parts you "don't need" slow execution, and add unnecessary code (primal sin)